# タスクトレイのメソッドやプロパティなどでエラー

Tags: rad-studio

現在、RAD Studio 10.3でプログラミングを行っています。

```cpp
class TfrmMain : public TForm
{
-------------(中略)-------------------
public:
TTrayIcon *pTray;
-------------(中略)-------------------
}


id __fastcall TfrmMain::FormCloseQuery(TObject *Sender, bool &CanClose)
{
-------------(中略)-------------------
      pTray->Minimize();
-------------(中略)-------------------
}
```

pTray->Minimize();行で次のようなエラーができてきます。

> [bcc32c エラー] Main.cpp(1708): no member named 'Minimize' in 'Vcl::Extctrls::TTrayIcon'

このMinimize()というメソッドや

```cpp
pTray->BiMaximize;
pTray->Hide = true;
pTray->Minimize();
pTray->Restore();
```

これらのメソッドやプロパティアクセスでエラーが出ます。
TTrayIconのドキュメントでも最新のものではなくなってしまったようなのですが、同等の機能のものはありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimize()は

```
   Application->Minimize();
   ShowWindow(Application->Handle, SW_HIDE);
```

Restore()は

```
   Application->Restore();
   ShowWindow(Application->Handle, SW_RESTORE);
   SetForegroundWindow(Application->Handle);
```

C++Builder6のTTrayIconのソースを見る限りだと上記のように置き換えたら良いのでは無いかと思います。
Hideはソースを見る限りでは意味の無いプロパティぽいので、他で参照してないのなら恐らく消しても問題無いのではないかと思います。
BiMaximizeは良く判りません。

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。助かります。